# Solving modular equations in maple

Tags: maple, modular-arithmetic

I want to ask Maple, for example, for which `j` the following is true:

`10^j mod 543 = 82`

How can I ask Maple this?

Also, is there a way to solve for `j` without a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the The Discrete Logarithm Problem. It is a difficult problem---computationally intensive. See the Wikipedia page. It has discussion of eight algorithms for the problem. The Maple command is **numtheory:-mlog**.

```
numtheory:-mlog(82, 10, 543);
```

Maple responds

```
 12
```

To obtain all such integers j, use the extended form of the command:

```
numtheory:-mlog(82, 10, 543, 'c');
```

Maple again responds with 12, and c is set to 180, meaning that j = 12 + 180*k is a solution for any nonnegative integer k.